# Stretching a user control in a grid view

Tags: c#, gridview, user-controls, win-universal-app

I have a usercontrol in a `GridView` in a uwp app.I want the usercontrol to be stretched in the `Gridview`'s `ItemsPanel`. I tried to set the `HorizontolAlignment` of the usercontrol to `Stretch`but no success.Someone knows the solution?

here's the xaml of the usercontrol

```
<UserControl
x:Class="LessonsBuild.Controls.TextItemControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:LessonsBuild.Controls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="614"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 

Margin="5"
Height="Auto">

<Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent },Path=Width}"
      Height="Auto"  >
    <Rectangle x:Name="DropShadow" 
               Margin="5,5,0,0"
               Fill="{StaticResource DropShadowBrush }"/>

    <Grid x:Name="Root" 
          Width ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent },Path=Width}"
          Height="Auto"  
          Margin="0,0,3,3"
          Background="White" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    

            <!--#region Header-->
        <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent },Path=Width}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitel"
                       Text="{x:Bind CurrentModel.Title}"
                       FontSize="30"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
            <StackPanel x:Name="controls"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" >

                <AppBarButton   x:Name="btnBold"
                              Icon="Bold" 
                              Click="btnBold_Click" />

                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnItalic"
                              Icon="Italic"  
                              Click="btnItalic_Click"  />

                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnUnderline"
                              Icon="Underline" 
                              Click="btnUnderline_Click"  />

                <AppBarButton x:Name="btnBullet"
                              Icon="Bullets" 
                              Click="btnBullet_Click"  />


            </StackPanel>

            <AppBarButton x:Name="btnDelete"
                          Grid.Column="2"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          Icon="Delete" 
                          Click="btnDelete_Click" 
                />


        </Grid>
            <!--#endregion-->

        <!--#region  Content-->
        <RichEditBox x:Name="txtBox"
            Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0,1"
                     TextChanged="txtBox_TextChanged"
                     >

        </RichEditBox>

        <!--#endregion-->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Heres the `GridView`s xaml

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="30"
              ItemsSource="{Binding TextControlList}" SelectionMode="None" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  />
```

[image]

Comment: make sure you have not given any height or width in the user control. however design height and width does not have any impact. else you can provide the code for user control and gridview to help.

Comment: Could you please post XAML code?

Comment: @Sakura  I updated the question with xaml code.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a ListView instead of a GridView

Answer (score 2):

To adjust it, modify the item of HorizontalContentAlignment as Stretch, within the '**ItemContainerStyle**' (NOT within the gridview itself).
In list/gridview control, you can modify the way of item placement via this ItemContainerStyle.

```
<GridView x:Name="yourGridView" .... >
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm ok with the 'ItemContainer' but the problem is the usercontrol doesn't get stretched. even the 'HorizontalContentAlignment' is set to 'stretch'.